# Replace a substring in each element of a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, substring

Hey, I have an array of strings and I want to replace a certain substring in each of those elements. Is there an easy way to do that besides iterating the array explicitly?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could iterate the array *implicitly*

```
arrayOfStrings = arrayOfStrings.Select(s => s.Replace("abc", "xyz")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Strictly this does not replace elements in the array, it creates a new array with the replaced elements in. This makes i difference if the original arrayOfStrings was referenced elsewhere, like if arrayOfStrings was an in parameter in a method.

Comment: @grady you can not use foreach(var s in arrayOfStrings) {s = s.Replace("foo", "bar"); } since you are not allowed to modify the foreach variable.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, anything you do is going to do *exactly* that anyway. A simple `for` loop should be fine. There are pretty solutions involving lambdas, such as `Array.ConvertAll` / `Enumerable.Select`, but tbh it isn't necessary:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) arr[i] = arr[i].Replace("foo","bar");
```

(the `for` loop has the most efficient handling for *arrays*; and `foreach` isn't an option due to mutating the iterator variable)